# Тень без использования фотошопа

Tags: css3

Возможно ли реализовать такую тень без фотошопа?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
* + * {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

div {
  height: .5em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
  margin: -1em auto 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .5em 0px black;
}

.b-50:before {
  width: 50%;
}

.b-75:before {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class=b-50></div>
<div class=b-75></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Сразу напомню, что к `img` псевдоэлементы не применяются. Поэтому обязательно оборачиваем тег в обертку. И получаем следующее:

```css
.image-block { 
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
}
.image-block:after {
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    width: 90%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: none;    
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
img {
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-block">
  <img src="http://yurkons24.ru/block-12-img-1.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Мне нужно <header> обвернуть и что бы он был во всю ширину

Comment: это немного не то

Comment: Вставьте кусочек кода Header

Comment: вместо image-block ставим <header>.